# Prove that $K_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Prove that $K_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, where $K_4$ is Klein's-$4$-group.

My solution goes like this :

> We know that, $K_4=\{e,a,b,ab\}$ and $$\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}.$$ We define $f:K_4\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$, such that $f(e)=(0,0),f(a)=(0,1),f(b)=(1,0),f(ab)=(1,1).$ We can verify that $f$ is a homomorphism. Now, $f$ is clearly onto. Also, $f$ is injective as well. Thus $f$ is an isomorphism. Hence, $K_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

Is the solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong ?

**UPDATE 1**

**Using KCd's suggestions in the comment section, I tried building the proof as follows:**

> We consider $f:\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2\longrightarrow K_4$, such that $f(m,n)=a^mb^n$, $\forall m,n\in\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$. Now, $f$ is a homomorphism, $f((m_1,n_1)(m_2,n_2))=f(m_1+m_2,n_1+n_2)=a^{m_1+m_2}b^{n_1+n_2}=a^{m_1+m_2}b^{n_1+n_2}=a^{m_1}b^{n_1}a^{m_2}b^{n_2}=f((m_1,n_1))f((m_2,n_2)),\forall (m_1,n_1),(m_2,n_2)\in \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z^2$. Now,$\forall a^mb^n\in\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2 $, $f([m],[n])=a^mb^n$. Hence, $f$ is onto. Now, to prove $f$ is injective, we work the values of $f$, i.e $f([0],[0])=e,f([0],[1])=b,f([1],[0])=a,f([1],[1])=ab$. Thus, $f$ is injective. Thus, $K_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: "We can verify that $f$ is a homomorphism".  It doesn't look like you verified it at all, but only *said* you did.  You could just as well say "We can verify the whole result" and I hope that lets you see the unsatisfactory nature of how you checked $f$ is a homomorphism. I think it is simpler to build a mapping the *other* way $(\mathbf Z_2)^2 \to K_4$ by $(m,n) \mapsto a^mb^n$. Compute that *this* is a homomorphism. Don't just say you can "verify it".

Comment: @KCd But how to prove this mapping injective?

Comment: You have to prove also that your $f$ preserves the operation, namely: $f(a^2)=2f(a)$, $f(b^2)=2f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$.

Comment: @Devo No, I was talking about KCd's prove. How to prove the mapping that he demonstrated in the comment to be injective?

Comment: My comment was to your attempt, not to your thoughts

Comment: @Devo Thoughts? you mean my proof, right?when you talked about preserving operations?

Comment: Yes, @Arthur. Did you get my comment with reference to your (incomplete) proof?

Comment: It is a function from a 4-element set to a 4-element set: just work out the values directly.

Comment: @KCd I have edited my post, is it correct, now?

Comment: @Devo I get it now, I have edited my post

Comment: Working out the values shows $f$ is a bijection, not just that it is injective.

Comment: @KCd Hmm...you are right Nevertheless,  is the proof ok, now?I mean the proof in **UPDATE 1** *section*? 